# How to keep the space above an Header element, even if the header element is not present?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

Here is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8kYS.png) of my Title and Image. As you can see, there is space above the Title and the blue line. However, if there is no Title, then the space above the Title is gone and the images are now closer to the blue line, [example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmE1n.png). How can I still keep the space above the title, even if there is no title? **Basically, I don't want my images to move up closer to the blue line, even if there is no Title, I want that space to remain in place.**

I tried applying `min-height` on the title class, but still there is no space, when there is no header

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class = "myComponentWrapper">
 <div class = "myContainer"
  <div class = "Title">
     <h2 class = "headTitle"> This my Header</h2>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class "image">
  <img class="myImage" .......>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to be careful with your code:

- Use kebab-case for CSS class names
- Use double space for indentation
- Don't add spaces around `=` when setting an attribute

Now, to solve your problem, I think all you need to do is to reset the margin for the h2 element to make sure that the total height h2 + margin is smaller than the `min-height` you set for the title container.

Try this and see if it solves your problem:

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="my-component-wrapper">
      <div class="my-container">
        <div class="title">
          <h2 class="head-title">This my Header</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="image">
        <img
          class="my-image"
          src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x200"
          alt=""
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
/* style.css */
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.my-image {
  width: 100%;
}

.title {
  min-height: 60px;
}

.head-title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I will give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple ways to do it. I am going to describe one that I find simple.

#### Use conditional margins

You can find out(by inspecting) how much height the header takes plus the gap between the header and the image and then what you can do is apply conditional margin top to the `.image` class to achieve it.

Assuming the height of header + gap is 40px and the gap itself is 20px, here's what you can do.

```css
/* We give this margin-top by default. This includes header height + gap*/
.image {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

/* If there's myContainer div, which i am assuming only comes in when you have the header, we reduce that margin top to 20px to compensate for the header that exists.*/
.myContainer + .image {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

You could also give a specific height to your header element and then this calculation would become a little easier for you instead of finding the taken up vertical space by inspecting.

**NOTE**: you also need to worry about the `line-height` of the `h2` element if you aren't specifying a particular height for it. In that case, you need to add the computed `line-height` along with the gap between the header and the image and then use that as the `margin-top` instead of 40px as shown above.

**Update:**

If the assumptions I made are wrong, then you can't use the sibling selector to apply those rules. In that case you need to either change your markup to make the header and the image as siblings or may be choose a more complicated route and use JavaScript(not preferred).

Semantically, I would like to keep them as siblings if I can(assuming I have control over the markup generation). In that scenario, it would look like this.

```html
 <div class = "myContainer"
  <div class = "Title">
     <h2 class = "headTitle"> This my Header</h2>
  </div>
  <div class "image">
     <img class="myImage" .......>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Then I would use the same sibling selector trick to get the thing done.

#### JavaScript Way

If you do not have control over markup generation, you can use JS to conditionally apply the margins.

````js
// Rough example of what you can do assuming the height of header is 20px.
// If you want to find out the height of header dynamically, use
// ```header.offsetHeight``` and add that with 20px(assumed gap height) and apply that as margin top. 

const header = document.querySelector(".headTitle");
const image = document.querySelector(".image");
if(header) {
  image.style.marginTop = '20px';
} else {
  image.style.marginTop = '40px';
}
````

Comment: myContainer will still remain, even if there is no header.

Comment: I made an update to the answer to address that.

Comment: I updated the first picture in my question to make it clear. I am not sure how can I keep the space even if there is no header.

Comment: The place that you have marked as SPACE, remains fixed. Say 60px. Then you place your markup the way I have suggested and depend on their existence to adjust the margins and space below.

Comment: problem is I don't have control over the markup.

Comment: In that case, you need to use JavaScript to check for existence of the header and depending on whether or not that exists, you'll need to apply correct margin-top to image element.

Comment: any examples of how I can achieve this in JS?

Answer (score 0):

Set min-height value for your title that would be equivalent to it's line-height value. In such a way space for your title won't collapse even without text content.

```css
.headTitle {
  min-height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px; // set these values as you want, they just need to be equal
}
```

```html
<div class = "myComponentWrapper">
 <div class = "myContainer"
  <div class = "Title">
     <h2 class = "headTitle"> This my Header</h2>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class "image">
  <img class="myImage" .......>
 </div>
</div>
```